# xeditable row com 2 formulários

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um formulário principal na página, e dentro dele tenho uma aba de parcelas, onde o usuário pode inserir quantas parcelas quiser e elas vão cada uma, para uma linha de uma table (dentro do form principal).
É em cada uma dessas linhas, que quero usar o xeditable, para que o usuário possa alterar a parcela na própria linha.

Peguei o exemplo lá do angular do xeditable, porém , como essas linhas estão dentro de um form principal, não está funcionando.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de solução? Sabe se funciona?

Aqui tem um exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/
Porém, se vocês acrescentarem um form por fora da tabela, verão que nao funciona também, que é o meu caso!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar esses atributos em seus inputs:

```
 class="editable-click" ng-click="$form.$show()" e-ng-blur="$form.$hide()"
```

Comment: Olá, não adiantou :/ eu tenho um form principal, e dentro dele a tabela que quero editar, e pra implementar o row editable, tem que pôr outro formulário dentro, fica um form dentro de um form.

Comment: tentei colocar esses atributos na td que vai ser editada e também no botão de edição, não funcionou corretamente em nenhum caso. Esse formulário por fora ferra com tudo. :/

Comment: colocando ng-click="$form.$show()" e-ng-blur="$form.$hide()", ele abre todas as linhas e colunas pra edição, ao invés de somente a linha clicada.